# Oozie workflow with spark application reports out of memory

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, memory, workflow, oozie

I’ve tried to execute Oozie workflow with spark program as single step.
I've used jar which is successfully executed with spark-submit or spark-shell (the same code):

```
spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0  --master yarn-client --class "SimpleApp"  /tmp/simple-project_2.10-1.1.jar
```

Application shouldn’t demand lot of resources – load single csv (<10MB) to hive using spark.

- Spark version: 1.6.0
- Oozie version: 4.1.0

Workflow is created with Hue, Oozie Workflow Editor:

```
<workflow-app name="Spark_test" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    <start to="spark-589f"/>
    <kill name="Kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <action name="spark-589f">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
                    <value>-XX:MaxPermSize=2g</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <master>yarn</master>
            <mode>client</mode>
            <name>MySpark</name>
            <jar>simple-project_2.10-1.1.jar</jar>
              <spark-opts>--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0</spark-opts>
            <file>/user/spark/oozie/jobs/simple-project_2.10-1.1.jar#simple-project_2.10-1.1.jar</file>
        </spark>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

I got following logs after running workflow:

stdout:

> Invoking Spark class now >>>
>   Invocation of Main class completed <<<
>
> Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], exception invoking main(), PermGen space

stderr:

> Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Yarn application state monitor"
>   Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], exception invoking main(), PermGen space

syslog:

> 2017-03-14 12:31:19,939 ERROR [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Error running child : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Please suggest which configuration parameters should be increased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least 2 options here:
1) increase PermGen size for launcher MR job by adding this to workflow.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
    <value>-XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</value>
</property>
```

see details here: http://www.openkb.info/2016/07/memory-allocation-for-oozie-launcher-job.html

2) preferred way is to use Java 8 instead of outdated Java 7

Comment: Java 7 comes with CDH 5.9.0, I didn't want to change it. Does this situation won't occur with java 8?

Answer (score 0):

PermGen memory is a non-heap memory which is used to store the class metadata and string constants. It will not usually grow drastically if there are no runtime class loading by class.forname() or any other third-party JARs. 
If you get this error message as soon as you launch your application, then it means that the allocated permanent generation space is smaller than actually required by all the class files in your application.

"-XX:MaxPermSize=2g"

You already set 2gb for PermGen memory. You can increase this value gradually and see which value does not throw outofmemoryerror and keep that value. You can also use profilers to monitor the memory usage of permanent generation and set the right value.

If this error is triggered at run time, then it might be due to runtime class loading or excessive creation of string constants in permanent generation. It requires profiling your application to fix the issue and set the right value for -XX:MaxPermSize parameter.